# Scrolling DIVs on iPad and Android

Tags: css, ipad, html, overflow

Ok, I am trying to wrap my mind around what exactly makes a div scrollable, and what kills that scrollable functionality on iPad and Android (so I guess any mobile webkit).

Lets say I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="inner">
  <div class="dynamic_content"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So minimally I would set **overflow:auto;** on the **#wrapper**.

I also see from reading around here that **#wrapper** should have fixed dimensions (so assuming fixed height and width).

What about **#inner** or **.dynamic_content** divs? Anything special (CSS) for those?

What if I have javascript resizing **#wrapper** when user resizes the browser -- does that affect anything?

I am asking this because I have a few things that use a similar DOM as I have explained above which scroll just fine on iPad, and others that DO NOT scroll, and I cannot figure out what else may be affecting the functionality.

So the general question is, are there a set of rules to follow to get scrolling to work, and a secondary question is what kinds of other forces can affect and/or break that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm i'm also interested in this question - I've had the same experience more or less with a webview in android. I hope someone knows the answer to this.

Comment: See http://fioravengi.blogspot.hu/2011/06/implications-of-ios-5-webkit-overflow.html , http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement a scrollable <div> on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976111/how-can-i-implement-a-scrollable-div-on-ipad)