# How to make div scrollable in ipad?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

When i try on desktop the **div** scrolling works. But in ipad it doesn't work. 
Here is my code.

Html:

```
<div id="devicesContent" >
     <table></table>
</div>
```

css:

```
#devicesContent{
      position: absolute;
      top: -625px;
      height: 565px;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

What am i missing?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976111/how-can-i-implement-a-scrollable-div-on-ipad  or use TWO fingers on the div!!! That's it

Answer (score 2):

[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) Works just like the native controls that have one-finger scrolling.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The scrolling is working now but i have inside the div buttons and they are unclickable now!